# Regular expression to Remove html tags and Data between those tags

Tags: regex, python3

I have tried a lot of things but still unable to figure out due to greedy nature of regular expression

`abc = 'dfbafbd<a href="#Free_Calling_Best_Apps">Free Calling Best Apps</a>sbrwsggsfzbs<a></a>abc`

My regular expression
`abc1 = re.sub(r'<a.+\/a>',' ',abc)`

output = 'dfbafbd abc'

required output = 'dfbafbd sbrwsggsfzbs abc'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make your regex not greedy:

```
abc1 = re.sub(r'<a.+?/a>',' ',abc)
#            here __^
```

But [Parsing HTML with regex is a hard job](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4234491/372239).

HTML and regex are not good friends. Use a parser, it is simpler, faster and much more maintainable.

Comment: @abhavluthra: You're welcome, glad it helps. Feel free to mark the answer as accepted, see: https://superuser.com/help/someone-answers